# refactoring an array

Tags: php, amfphp

I have the following result in AMFPHP from a sql query:

```
(Array)#0
  [0] (Object)#1
    id = "1"
    naam = "4 kazen"
    pizzeria_id = "1"
    pizzerianaam = "Howest pizza"
    prijs = "11"
  [1] (Object)#2
    id = "2"
    naam = "Napolitano"
    pizzeria_id = "1"
    pizzerianaam = "Howest pizza"
    prijs = "13"
  [2] (Object)#3
    id = "5"
    naam = "pizza bolognaise"
    pizzeria_id = "2"
    pizzerianaam = "Nicola pizza"
    prijs = "12"
  [3] (Object)#4
    id = "6"
    naam = "pizza funghi"
    pizzeria_id = "2"
    pizzerianaam = "Nicola pizza"
    prijs = "16"
```

what i would like to do is refactor this array so the result is a  assosiative array with 2 arrays inside of it, the 2 arrays should be called after the "pizzerianaam" and within the "pizzerianaam" i should see the pizza's where the "pizzerianaam" matches.

so an array with 2 arrays in it wich contains other arrays for each pizza where the "pizzerianaam" value matches.

Anyone who ca help?

Comment: Good practice is to keep names of all identifiers in English. It eg. helps when you are asking for help on international sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the result of the query is stored in `$array`

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $item)
{
  $result[$item->pizzerianaam][] = $item;
}
```

then the resulting array will be `$result`.

Comment: Use serialize(http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to serialize the array. That way people can unserialize the array to test whether the suggested solution works. My code is correct according to the array that you have given.